# confusion about .html() and .append() when I'm trying to overwrite elements in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry about the gory title. Effectively I'm trying to loop through a 2 dimensional array and I'm using autocomplete to output every time a single character is changed. If I use `.append` or `.prepend` then I have a long list of characters and that's not quite what I want, I'd like to overwrite every character change so that I'm not stuck with 50 results. I tried using `.html` and while it works to some extent (it overwrites) it only outputs the last element in the 2 dimensional array, which isn't quite what I want since I'd like to output all elements in the array.

Here is my code:

```
for(var i = 0, len = data[1].length; i < len; i++) {
    var currentDesc = data[2][i];
    if(currentDesc.indexOf("may refer to:") <= -1) {
        $('#results').append('<div id="allResults"><a href="'+ data[3][i] +'">'+ data[1][i] +'</a><div id="descResults">'+ data[2][i] +'</div></div>');
    }
}
```

Any ideas? I've just tried `.html()`, `.append`, and `.prepend`

Comment: share your 2 dimensional array.

Comment: @Vaibhav My 2 dimensional array looks like this:
`["Red", "Redshift", "Redox", "Red Skelton", "Red Sea", "Red Barn Murder", "Red rail", "Rediff", "Red fox", "Red-necked grebe"]` in `.html` it becomes more like a 1 dimensional array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should blank your $('#result') with $('#result').html('') **before** your for() statement, and then use .append() inside the loop.

Could you provide your array so as I can confirm that I understood well your problem ?

Comment: My 2 dimensional array looks like this:
`["Red", "Redshift", "Redox", "Red Skelton", "Red Sea", "Red Barn Murder", "Red rail", "Rediff", "Red fox", "Red-necked grebe"]` in `.html` it becomes more like a 1 dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
$('#results').html('<div id="allResults"><a href="'+ data[3][i] +'">'+ data[1][i] +'</a><div id="descResults">'+ data[2][i] +'</div></div>')
```

then contents of `$('#results')` are replacted by the new string on each loop iteration.

So you may leave `.append` inside the loop and clear contents of `#results` before entering the for loop, as Robin suggested. Either with `$('#results').html('')` or `$('#results').empty()`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to address the array the other way around.

Use `data[i][3]` instead of `data[3][i]`:

```
for(var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
    var currentDesc = data[i][2];
    if(currentDesc.indexOf("may refer to:") <= -1) {
        $('#results').append('<div id="allResults"><a href="'
            + data[i][3] +'">'+ data[i][1] 
            +'</a><div id="descResults">'+ data[i][2] +'</div></div>');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things, dont append in a for loop, and when you are adding some html code which can come multiple time, dont use id. You can use this:

```
var currentDesc, resultHTML='<div id="allResults">';
for(var i = 0, len = data[1].length; i < len; i++) {
    currentDesc = data[2][i];
    if(currentDesc.indexOf("may refer to:") <= -1) {
        resultHTML +='<a href="'+ data[3][i] +'">'+ data[1][i] +'</a><div class="descResults">'+ data[2][i] +'</div>';
    }
}
resultHTML += '</div>';
$('#results').append(resultHTML);
```